# Changing default files permission in Linux

Tags: linux, file, directory, permissions, umask

I work under Centos 7.
For some time, I have a problem with the FTP **/home/students** directory whose access rights( permission) is set to 750. When I create a file as user *students* the file access permission is 644 (read/write for the owner and read-only for other users). But when the students user receives files by SFTP (with authentication by ssh key), the permission of these files is 600.
Can the right of access (permission) be imposed by the one who uploads the file by SFTP?

How to make the default permission for files received by SFTP automatically 644?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think u should do something like this > Modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -m 0644
```

Then u should reload the SSHD Configuration :

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you Azis

Comment: If you've try it and it worked, please check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers